# How do I make the string a raw string literal so that I can run cv2.imread() on it?

Tags: python, string, literals, opencv

```
one = (r"C:\Users\Sam\OneDrive\Desktop\RateData\1")

for feature in features[0]:
    backslash = '\\'
    imagePath = ((one)+backslash+"'"+str(feature)+"'")
    img = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    print(imagePath)
    print(img)
```

---

So the result of `print(imagePath)` is: 
   `C:\Users\Sam\OneDrive\Desktop\RateData\1\'1.1.jpg'`

---

The result of `print(img)` is:    `None`

---

`feature` is just the image file name.  I wrote it like that so it would add the unique image file name to the path.

So I tried running that through the `cv2.imread()` function and it returned `None`.
I know that the reason it won't run is that it is just reading it as a string and doesn't recognize that as a raw string literal. I'm not a very experienced programmer so I tried all the ways I could think of (not very many) to get it to read the path as a raw string literal and it didn't work. So if any of you could help me out in making the string into that that would be awesome!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: "I know that the reason it won't run is that it is just reading it as a string and doesn't recognize that as a literal" - whatever your concepts of "string" and "literal" are, they don't match how Python actually works. Why are you trying to stick single-quotes into your file path at all? Does your file name actually have those single-quotes in it?

Comment: Is the problem that you build the path `C:\Users\Sam\OneDrive\Desktop\RateData\1\'1.1.jpg` but wanted to build a different path, or that you build that path and wanted to build that path and don't understand why there's no file named `'1 1.jpg` in that `RateData` directory?

Comment: To answer both of your comments, `C:\Users\Sam\OneDrive\Desktop\RateData\1\'1.1.jpg` is an acceptable path and I've gotten it to work in the code if I type in: `r"C:\Users\Sam\OneDrive\Desktop\RateData\1\'1.1.jpg'"`. It works the same as: `r"C:\Users\Sam\OneDrive\Desktop\RateData\1\1.1.jpg"`. The reason I need the "r" in the front of the path is so that I don't get an unicode error. Also, it's my bad that I used the word "literal". I should have used "raw string." The reason for my posting was to figure out how to make `imagePath` a raw string, but as it turns out I don't need that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So the result of "print(imagePath) is: C:\Users\Sam\OneDrive\Desktop\RateData\1\'1.1.jpg

Almost certainly, you don't have a file named `'1.1.jpg` in the `RateData` directory. While Windows does allow apostrophe/single-quote characters in filenames, I can't imagine you would have used one there intentionally. So, it's probably named `1.1.jpg`?

I'm also not sure how you got that string out of that code… but never mind that.

---

You're making this all a lot harder than it has to be. There's no need to worry about getting path separators escaped and quoted properly, or whatever you were trying to do.

Python comes with the [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) module for doing path-related operations. So just use it:

```
for feature in features[0]:
    imagePath = os.path.join(one, str(feature))
    img = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    print(imagePath)
    print(img)
```

Or, since I'd bet `feature` is already a string, even simpler:

```
    imagePath = os.path.join(one, feature)
```

---

Or, if you prefer a more object-oriented API, Python also comes with [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
one = pathlib.Path(one)
for feature in features[0]:
    imagePath = one / feature
    img = cv2.imread(str(imagePath))
    print(imagePath)
    print(img)
```

I don't know if `cv2` is pathlib-aware, but if it is, you can just do `cv2.imread(imagePath)`. (If you want to use `pathlib`, definitely try that and see, because it's obviously more readable.)

Comment: To explain what I was trying to do was, I was trying to piece together a string to make a path for a file. I didn't know about os.path.join until you replied with it. Also if you read my other comment you will understand why I used `'1.1.jpg'` instead of just `1.1.jpg` and that was simply because I knew it worked the first way and I didn't bother to try it the other way. Your answer is a much better solution than what I was trying to do and it indeed worked perfectly. I still would like to know out of curiosity about how to make that string a raw string, because that would work too. Thank you!

Comment: @SamHall You can't "make a string a raw string". Raw strings aren't a thing. Strings just contain their characters. Raw string _literals_ are a way of representing strings in your source code. They affect how your source code is parsed, but once it's parsed, the string you get is just a plain old string, and, e.g., `r'C:\Spam'` and `'C:\\Spam'` are the exact same string. So, what you're trying to do doesn't make sense, so it can't be a solution to your problem.

Comment: So instead of using that silly concatenation I was trying to use, I put in the full path instead: `r"C:\Users\fatso\OneDrive\Desktop\RateData\1\1.1.jpg"` and set that equal to `imagePath`. I just understood that the `r` in front of the path made it work, so when I asked this I was just trying to find a way to make my concatenation a raw string literal even though I didn't realize it was called a raw string literal. But anyways you're saying that making that concatenation a raw string literal is not possible?

Comment: @SamHall I'm saying that it doesn't _mean_ anything. If you concatenate `r"C:\Users\fatso\OneDrive\Desktop\RateData\1" + "\\" + "1.1.jpg"`, what you get is the same string as r"C:\Users\fatso\OneDrive\Desktop\RateData\1\1.1.jpg"`.

Comment: Also I am kind of new to stackoverflow so I was wondering, could send me a few pointers to writing a good question because I don't want to get banned from asking questions? I am a relatively new programmer and as I get into more complex things it becomes helpful to ask questions and I don't want that privelege being taken away. If you would, could you please tell me what's wrong with this post so I can make it better? I have read the guidelines and I thought I was in the green but apparently not. If you don't have time I understand, but anyways thank you for the time you put into helping me!

Comment: @SamHall Honestly, I think at least some of the downvotes here were not so much about the way you asked your question, as about the fact that you were too confused about what you're asking—which really is more about being a novice programmer than anything else. It's not fair that people get downvoted for that, but they do. But as for things you _can_ do something about:

Comment: @SamHall … maybe formatting. Use backticks, not quotes, to refer to code bits, like `print(imagePath)` and `feature`. Don't go overboard with headers/bold/etc. Make sure your quotes are balanced. (Make sure you look at the preview before clicking Save.) Most of that stuff shouldn't matter, but it affects people subconsciously, so they're more likely to see you as "not a professional, student, or serious hobbyist", and dismiss you. Also, "Thanks for the help!" sounds friendly (because it is), but it doesn't really fit the style here, which probably doesn't help. Lots of silly little things…

Comment: Alright, I really appreciate you taking the time out of your day to help me out! I'll make sure to think about your pointers before the next time I post, thanks!